# selecting file to play from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwplayer

I am stuck with playing videos on my ruby on rails application.

I have following line to play video on views file

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player ...</div>
```

my script for playing file is:

```
function myFunction(a) {
        jwplayer("#myElement").setup({ file: a.title, width: 540 });
}
```

I am calling this function from a div `onclick`.

While debugging using browser console i have noticed

```
ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined
```

I have installed `gem 'jw_player_helper'`

I am not sure, what i have missed here. plz point me to right direction
Thanks

Comment: what's your rails version?

Comment: i am using `rails 4.0.5`

Comment: have you included javascript in your HTML?

Comment: as Santosh said have you included `<%= javascript_include_tag 'swfobject' %>`?

Comment: yes i already have `<%= javascript_include_tag 'swfobject' %>` in my application layout

Comment: I think you must remove `#` from your element. This is not jQuery.

Comment: @RubyRacer nothing happened after i removed `#`

Comment: Since you are not using the helper method provided by the gem (which by the way is very, very specific), why don't you just download the jwplayer.js and use it?

Comment: @RubyRacer while searching to solve this, i just have added `jwplayer.js` file. Error is gone now. but i still cant see my video player

Comment: Have you removed `#`? Read the online javascript API reference and try, try, try...

Comment: i already ahve removed `#`, and i am trying again and again and again :)

Comment: Is there a link online that we can look at?

Comment: It was both path issue and file format issue. Thanks. I have fixed that :)